# Are there any other open source JCE libraries besides BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, jce

I am looking for open source JCE libraries that implement some of the more esoteric encryption algorithms so that I can study their implementation. I would be especially interested in ones that implement Identity Based Encryption (IBE) as published by Stanford.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptix (not sure what state its in at the moment but it was high quality when I used it last):

[http://www.cryptix.org](http://www.cryptix.org/)

[http://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptix/)

Comment: Cryptix is not active. I wouldn't call it high quality either. For example, it's PGP support does not respect the crypto provider preferences configured by the user. And since it hasn't had any activity for five years, it's not likely to algorithms that are currently considered "esoteric".

Comment: 5 years ago was probably when I last used it :-)

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Classpath](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/) also has their own JCE implementation, however, whether they support IBE is another story.